# Reference a file in C static library

Tags: c, static

I created a static library in C using Visual Studio. This library contains a function which accesses a text file stored in that current directory. The library was built properly. But the problem is that when I call the function from outside other project it is not loading that text file( I linked the .lib file properly everything else is working except for loading of that file).

Any ideas how to load a text file from .lib file just by relative path??

Thanks in advance..

The following is the library test function definition

```
int test() 
{ 
   FILE *fp = fopen("hello.txt", "r"); 
   if(!fp) printf("File Error");
   return 0; 
}
```

The test.lib file is built and created for this.
Just accessing the current folder hello.txt file but when this function is called from other Project. it is saying File Error.

Comment: What does your code actually look like?

Comment: show the code of taht function which open that text file and the application which use that library

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference whether you load a file from inside lib code or from other code. Make sure, however, that you know what the current directory really is!

Comment: The following is the library test function definition#include <stdafx.h>

int test()
{
 FILE *fp = fopen("hello.txt", "r");
 if(!fp)
  printf("File Error");
 return 0;
} Just accessing the current folder hello.txt file but when this function is called from others it is saying file error

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code to look at the `errno`:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

...

    if(!fp) printf("File error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

And then look up the meaning of the errno on your operating system to see what's going on.

Comment: Did you mean `strerror(errno)`? You can also use `perror` instead as `if(!fp) { perror("fopen"); /*Handle error*/}`

Comment: duh... fixed (I did not see the arg initally, and it's been a long time since I have used C).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the fact that you're calling this function from a library is a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

What's most likely happening is that your `hello.txt` file is not in the [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of the executing process. Go ahead and `#include <windows.h>` in your project, and use the [`GetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to see what the working directory is when you run your program. Most likely, it's not the same path as your text file.

To remedy this, you can do one of two things: you can change the startup settings of the program (whether that's from Visual Studio or a Windows shortcut) to specify the working directory (called "Start in:" for a Windows shortcut) to be the path to the text file you want to open, or you can figure out what working directory your program has been using and move your text file there instead.

**Edit:** Also, if you want the application to use its own directory (where the executable file actually resides) you can use the [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function to get the full path of the executable. Of course, you'll have to trim the filename of the program off the end of the string it produces, but that should be a piece of cake.

Answer (score -2):

Check your file path and print an errno, I think you have a static file path

Comment: -1. While this is *technically* accurate, it's horribly terse and uninformative.